# How to fix "NoClassDefFoundError" with BCrypt (org.mindrot.BCrypt)?

Tags: java, minecraft, bcrypt

I try to create a **Minecraft Plugin** (it's my first one) and I can't fix this **error**:

So, the plugin compiles good but when the code has to execute this code :

```java
BCrypt.checkpw(mdp, result.getString("mdp"))
```

that come from the lib org.mindrot.BCrypt, I have this error :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mindrot/BCrypt
```

But, when I open my JAR with WinRAR, there is my lib bcrypt (so it's well export). And it's also in my *.classpath*.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes what you presume to be correct is not. Can you print out the value of `System` property "java.class.path" from your plug-in when you run it? Here is an [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classnotfoundexception-and-noclassdeffounderror) on how to resolve `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Ok, indeed the `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`give me this : `spigot.jar` so there isn't my jbcrypt :/ How can I fix it ?

Comment: How do you launch _minecraft_ ? Do you launch it from the command line? If so, post the command you use.

Comment: `java -jar spigot.jar `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to configure the CLASSPATH when launching a java application via the `java` command. According to what you posted so far, I would use the `-classpath` flag:

```
java -classpath spigot.jar;jbcrypt.jar class.containing.main.method.MyMain
```

Alternatively, you could modify the MANIFEST in file `spigot.jar`. Refer to [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Or you could copy `jbcrypt.jar` to the directory pointed to by the java `System` property "java.ext.dirs".

Comment: But, i have an other lib (jdbc for mysql) and i didn't have to do all that things, why it don't work with jbcrypt and work with jdbc ?

Comment: As stated in the Web page I linked to in my answer, the MANIFEST of file `spigot.jar` probably contains a `Class-Path` directive which contains your other JARs. You can view the contents of the MANIFEST using _WinRAR_. Check it yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately not all words in French translate directly to English. For your information, in English we say _explanation_ and not _explication_ :-)

Comment: gloups, sorry :/